# Unrecognized value (commented-week)

Tags: dailymotion-api

I'm getting

```js
{"error":{"more_info":"https:\/\/developer.dailymotion.com\/api#error-codes","code":400,"message":"Unrecognized value (commented-week), allowed values are (recent, visited, visited-hour, visited-today, visited-week, visited-month, relevance, random, ranking,
trending, old, live-audience) for `sort' parameter","type":"invalid_parameter"}}
```

Have you removed "commented-week" sort type completely, is there any other alternative to get the most commented videos in a week when I do a search?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question adding what you're tried for `get the most commented videos in a week`.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#error-types) says:

> `invalid_parameter`:  Your request contains invalid parameters (e.g. **you set an invalid data type for a field**).

So, instead

> commented-week

Use:

> visited-week

Comment: Thanks! But I was looking for the most commented videos, not the most visited.